# Implementing custom (Facebook Platform) authentication in Strophe

Tags: javascript, strophe, facebook-chat

I'm trying to integrate a Facebook chat in a web application. I have to use *Facebook Platform Authentication* but AFAIK there's no built-in support for this in *Strophe* . So I ask :

Q:

- Is there a plugin or extension to accomplish this ?
- Otherwise what's the right way to get this done . I mean what's the right 
  way to implement and integrate custom authentication handlers with *Strophe*.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/rubenjgarciab/turedsocial/blob/dc12d71339ad509c946b5de727f2d77999153b02/strophe-plugins/src/facebook.js

Comment: Thanks very much . It seems t be very useful . I'll take a look right away. Thanks !